# Get value from twig tweak without additional markup

Tags: theming

I am using the following code to set a variable "tab1visibility" from the twig tweak value for field_hidden based on a block id.  `{% set tab1visibility =  drupal_field('field_hidden', 'block_content', 7)  %}`

This works perfectly but returns the value with the expected markup.

When I try to use |striptags on this newly created value it returns nothing.

So

```
{% set tab1visibility =  drupal_field('field_hidden', 'block_content', 7)  %}

<p>{{tab1visibility}}</p>
```

returns true or false wrapped in my typical field div templating.

```
{% set tab1visibility =  drupal_field('field_hidden', 'block_content', 7)  %}

<p>{{tab1visibility|striptags}}</p>
```

returns nothing no markup or the raw value.

How do I get just the value without the surrounding markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field formatter stores the field object inside of the render array for reference later, so that you can still access the raw values:

```
{% set field = drupal_field('field_example', 'block_content', 1) %}
{% set value = field['#items'].0.value %}
{{ value }}
```

This is the same for all field formatters.

---

Your approach might also work, if you `|render` the field first and then apply `|striptags`:

```
{{ tab1visibility|render|striptags }}
```

But not in a consistent way, because it depends on the specific field type and the configured field formatter.

Comment: The first option was exactly what I was looking for thanks @4k4 !

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the markup comes from [field.html.twig](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.6.12/core/modules/system/templates/field.html.twig) template. You can override that template for this field in your theme.
Another approach is to turn off the theming like follows.

```
{{ drupal_field('field_hidden', 'block_content', 7)|without('#theme') }}
```